# Sed issue parenthesis escape

Tags: bash, sed

I try to substitute a line in my .sql file with the sed command.

I encountered an issue when i try to "escape" the last parenthesis of the line.
I tried to escape it with a backlash , used simple and double quotes around it but the problem persist.

```
sed -i "s|\(select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE',\).*|\1"'${var}','PRC_BNE_JZ') from dual;"|" backup_script.sql
```

The actual result is the following error :
**syntax error near unexpected token `)'**

The expected result is to understand my error.

Comment: You bash escaping is wrong. The `${var}` is inside `'` single quotes and after that you have a space, the error comes from the shell that can't parse it. Count the `"` and `'` quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output to test against but this might be what you're looking for:

```
sed -i 's/\(select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('\''PACKAGE'\'',\).*/\1'"${var}"','\''PRC_BNE_JZ'\'') from dual;/' backup_script.sql
```

Don't use `|` as a delimiter since it's an ERE metacharacter and so makes your code confusing to read at best and can cause problems if/when you decide to use EREs later (via the `-E` arg).

Do always use single quotes around scripts and strings unless you have a very specific reason why you must not do so and fully understand all the implications.

Answer (score 1):

I do everything in single quotes, to prevent strange  expansions. To have a single quote in the string, I use `'\''` as in `' string '\'' rest of string '`. To have a variable I use `'"$var"'` as in `' string '"$var"' rest of string` to have it properly expanded and concatenated with the rest of the string.

The following works:

```
> var=var
> echo "select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE'," | 
> sed 's|\(select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('\''PACKAGE'\'',\).*|\1'\'"${var}"\'','\''PRC_BNE_JZ'\'') from dual;|'
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE','var','PRC_BNE_JZ') from dual;
```

But probably using `"` is probably easier in this case, as the string uses `'` everywhere, as in:

```
sed "s|\(select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE',\).*|\1'${var}','PRC_BNE_JZ') from dual;|"
```

The error comes from the shell that can't parse the arguments. Ex. for the following:

```
> echo abc)
main.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
main.sh: line 2: `echo abc)'
```

The following happens in your command:

```
sed -i " bla bla "'${var}','PRC_BNE_JZ') from dual;"|" backup_script.sql
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - could be 4th argument
                                       ^ - unquoted `)` is parsed by bash, as in subshell `( ... )`
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - 2nd argument
    ^^ - 1st argument to sed command
^^^ - run sed command
```